# Logger in passport.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, passport-saml

Is it possible to log requests send (and received) by passport.js authentication library? I would want to log generated requests.

Couple options that would be nice:

1. Pass a logger object to passport.js auth function, that then gets called by passport.js
2. Passport.js sends events, that you can listen, and then log based on their content.

Comment: 3. Use a global logger instance. But what exactly is your problem? Do you want people to choose which method you should use (which is opinion-based)?

Comment: I want to know which of those is even possible to use at the moment...

Comment: All of them are possible, in some form or another.

Comment: Well, if you can show how (for example option 1), then I believe you :).

Comment: You really have to be more elaborate on what exactly it is that you want (and tried). What specifically do you mean by "generated requests", for instance?

Comment: I haven't tried anything. I wish to log http requests send by passport.

Comment: That's why I'm asking to be more elaborate, because Passport itself doesn't make HTTP requests at all. Perhaps you're using a Passport strategy that does, but it's worthwhile to know which one (for instance, it may have built-in debug logging for stuff like that).

Comment: The strategy doesn't have built-in debug logging.